# Mapbox Studio: landuse=residential not available?

Tags: mapbox

I try to build a map for my stormchasing community. It is very important to see urban areas on the map. I tried to add a landuse=residential layer/filter but it seems Mapbox does not support this at all.

Any ideas or solutions on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the [Mapbox Streets v8 tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#landuse) does not contain a landuse=residential field. However, this type of data is available in OSM as shown [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse) and can be downloaded using Overpass Turbo - you can refer to the ["Add OpenStreetMap data to your Mapbox project" tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/) for steps on how to do that.

Once you've downloaded this data, you can [upload it to your Mapbox account](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/geospatial-data/), add it as a new [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#layers) to your map, and [style it](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#style-a-layer) accordingly.